# Performing an aggregate function (e.g., mean) across rows produces NaN

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I am working with an Ames, Iowa housing pricing dataset and ran into what I think is a simple issue.

I created a dataframe from a pivot table of average prices by year and month. I am trying to calculate an average monthly price.

When I do it, I get NaN instead of a float.

```
df_viz = pd.DataFrame(pd.pivot_table(df,index=['MoSold'], columns=['YrSold'],values=['SalePrice'],aggfunc='mean').to_records())
df_viz = df_viz.set_index(['MoSold'])
df_viz.columns = [hdr.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("'","").replace(", ","") \
                     for hdr in df_viz.columns]
df_viz['mean_monthly_saleprice']=df_viz.mean(axis=0)
df_viz
```

What gives? How to I fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: why dont you use pandas str replace. Pandas columns is also an index, so you can easily use the string replace method on it, pass multiple options to your regex and make your changes : df_viz.columns.str.replace(r'[()',]','')

Comment: Right, although that wasn't my question. I am more concerned about why I get NaN when I use .mean on columns that are floats and should produce a valid mean.

Comment: Because you're using the wrong axis... You want `axis=1` Look at the result of `df_viz.mean(axis=0)` It's a Series where the Index are the column labels, and the means are of the individual columns. So when you try to align that Series on the DataFrame, with a RangeIndex, nothing aligns and you get all `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely specify the wrong axis. Try:

```
df_viz['mean_monthly_saleprice']=df_viz.mean(axis=1)
```

---

As to why your original code returned na, `df_viz.mean(axis=0)` produces the means by column. The result is a series with the column names as labels:

```
SalePrice2006    <a number>
SalePrice2007    <a number>
SalePrice2008    <a number>
SalePrice2009    <a number>
SalePrice2010    <a number>
```

You then try to combine that series with the `df_viz` dataframe, which is labeled by `MoSold`. No label matched between the two indexes. Hence your result was na.

**Moral of the story**: index matters hugely in a dataframe. Pay good attention to them.

Comment: thank you! I can't believe I made that mistake. Appreciate your help.